# Interact with user files - discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord

Good evening, I've built a small discord bot for me and some friends in node.js. The bot has this function: once activated it keeps watching a folder, whenever a file with a certain extension is changed it uploads it and posts the link on channel.

While this works fine with the files on my machine, I was wondering if there was a way to keep track of files on the machine of the person who activates the bot with the chat command.

The main issue is that fs seems to be able to access only the machine in which the server is running, making this functionality of the bot completely useless once the bot will be hosted online.

Any idea?

Comment: No.  Discord will not expose the filesystems of users to other users.  That would have major security implications. What would be possible is for you to have a common repository of files on github (or svn, or similar), that the bot is aware of and tracking which you can let people modify.

Comment: I suspected that was the case, thank you